# Getting "Unexpected token " error while checking for Yeoman version SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Im working on adding a top placeholder enhancement using spfx extensions for sharepoint online

Got "Unexpected token " error while  creating spfx solution using : yo @microsoft/sharepoint
[image]

when checked the version of Yeoman ,got the same error.
please find the below image of the error :

[image]

Can anyone help me on this error?